# Python Speech Recognition modules

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a speech to text and text to speech transcription app. I tried modules by Google and IBM, can you suggest any other modules that are available offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the speech recognition modules or libraries supported by python and I have also mentioned the libraries that are available offline. please go through this [document](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) for more information

- CMU Sphinx (works offline)
- Google Speech Recognition
- Google Cloud Speech API
- Wit.ai
- Microsoft Azure Speech
- Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition (Deprecated)
- Houndify API
- IBM Speech to Text
- Snowboy Hotword Detection (works offline)
- Tensorflow
- Vosk API (works offline)
- OpenAI whisper (works offline)

Answer (score 0):

shameless plug-in :)

Picovoice also process speech data on-device and the Free Tier offers 6000 minutes (100 hours) per month.
https://picovoice.ai/

here's an STT tutorial with 3 lines of Python:
https://picovoice.ai/blog/transcribe-speech-to-text-with-three-lines-of-python/

-working for picovoice